# Siunitx Table Space Before Close Parenthesis

Tags: tables, siunitx, adjustbox

I have a problem with `siunitx`, such that a space is being added between the decimals and the closing parenthesis for every cell. The fix suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287866/table-formating-problem-with-siunitx-parenthesis-and-scientific-notation) did not work for me. A MWE is included below, with a screenshot identifying the issue.

I assume my `\sisetup{}` is to blame.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,adjustbox} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
 \centering
 \caption{Estimated Main Effects (Social Index)}
 \begin{adjustbox}{width = \textwidth, center}
\sisetup{
            detect-all,
            table-number-alignment = center,
            table-figures-integer = 1,
            table-figures-decimal = 3,
            table-space-text-post = ***,
            input-symbols = {()},
}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{6pt}}r*{4}{S[table-format = <1.2, table-number-alignment = center, table-column-width=2.5cm]}}
 \toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Unadjusted}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Adjusted}} \\
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{Effect}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{(SE)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{Effect}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{(SE)}} \\\cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{3-3}\cmidrule{4-4}\cmidrule{5-5} 
 \textbf{\textit{Vars1}} &  &  &  &  \\
 Var1 & 0.107 & (0.021) & 0.106 & (0.021) \\
 \textbf{\textit{Vars2}} &  &  &  &  \\
 Var2a & -0.041 & (0.029) & -0.039 & (0.029) \\
 Var2b & -0.085 & (0.030) & -0.083 & (0.030) \\
 Var2c & -0.130 & (0.030) & -0.134 & (0.029) \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
 \end{adjustbox}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem. Parenthesis are nearby numbers. However, I wold slightly change your table design:

- I wouldn't use `adjustbox`
- `\cmidrule` I would put below `multicolumn` cells
- In MWE I would shortened `\sisetup` to only necessary options, but removed lines don't influence on result.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\caption{Estimated Main Effects (Social Index)}
\sisetup{input-symbols = {()},
         table-format=-1.3,
         table-space-text-post={)},
        }

\begin{tabular}{r*{4}{S} }
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Unadjusted}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Adjusted}} \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-5}
        &   {\textit{Effect}}
                &   {\textit{(SE)}}
                            &   {\textit{Effect}}
                                        &   {\textit{(SE)}}  \\
        \midrule
\textbf{\textit{Vars1}}
    &       &           &           &                       \\
Var1   & 0.107 & (0.021)   & 0.106     & (0.021)               \\
\textbf{\textit{Vars2}}
    &       &           &           &                       \\
Var2a & -0.041 & (0.029)   & -0.039    & (0.029)               \\
Var2b & -0.085 & (0.030)   & -0.083    & (0.030)               \\
Var2c & -0.130 & (0.030)   & -0.134    & (0.029)               \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Strange, even this reproduces my error in my TeX.

Comment: @ironchefsakai, I tested proposed solution with yesterday updated MikTeX (which has recent  `siunitx` from 2020/02/25). Try to update your LateX installation. It might help/solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I will give that a shot—I'm on Linux Mint 19.1, so it's possible I have the wrong ppa.

Comment: I took your suggestion and installed MikTeX. Unfortunately, the issue persists. Is `siunitx` known to conflict with any other packages?

Answer (score 1):

I am also unable to reproduce the spacing issue you've encountered. (I use MacTeX2019.) Anyway, my main suggestion is that you *not* use the `adjustbox` package at all. Instead, use a plain `tabular*` environment whose overall width is set to `\textwidth`. The following code and the upper table in the screenshot show how this may be achieved.

For the table at hand, I'd say that it's not a particularly good idea to set its width to `\textwidth`. Instead, just typeset the table at its natural width to create a nice and compact "look", as is illustrated in the second table shown below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\sisetup{input-symbols = {()}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering 

\caption{Estimated Main Effects (Social Index)}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  r *{2}{S[table-format=-1.3,
           table-space-text-post = ***] % is this needed??
         S[table-format= 1.3,
           table-space-text-pre  = (,
           table-space-text-post = )]} @{}}
 \toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Unadjusted}} 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\textbf{Adjusted}} \\
 \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5}
 & {\textit{Effect}} & {\textit{(SE)}} 
 & {\textit{Effect}} & {\textit{(SE)}} \\
 \cmidrule{2-5} 
 \textbf{\textit{Vars1}} \\
 Var1  &  0.107 & (0.021) & 0.106 & (0.021) \\
 \addlinespace
 \textbf{\textit{Vars2}} \\
 Var2a & -0.041 & (0.029) & -0.039 & (0.029) \\
 Var2b & -0.085 & (0.030) & -0.083 & (0.030) \\
 Var2c & -0.130 & (0.030) & -0.134 & (0.029) \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip
\caption{Same table, but at natural width}
\begin{tabular}{@{}
  r *{2}{S[table-format=-1.3] 
         S[table-format= 1.3,
           table-space-text-pre  = (,
           table-space-text-post = )]} @{}}
 \toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Unadjusted}} 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\textbf{Adjusted}} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
 & {\textit{Effect}} & {\textit{(SE)}} 
 & {\textit{Effect}} & {\textit{(SE)}} \\
 \cmidrule(l){2-5} 
 \textbf{\textit{Vars1}} \\
 Var1  &  0.107 & (0.021) & 0.106 & (0.021) \\
 \addlinespace
 \textbf{\textit{Vars2}} \\
 Var2a & -0.041 & (0.029) & -0.039 & (0.029) \\
 Var2b & -0.085 & (0.030) & -0.083 & (0.030) \\
 Var2c & -0.130 & (0.030) & -0.134 & (0.029) \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```