# How can I get a number like 6.76127E+17 in LaTex?

Tags: scientific-notation

How can I get a number like 6.76127E+17 in a LaTeX table?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. I think with siunitx package.

Comment: With siunitx, `\num{6.76127E17}` produces $6.761 27 \times 10^{17}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Related from this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132763/siunitx-and-e-notation-in-tables-with-s-column),

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  output-exponent-marker = \text{E},
  table-format=+1.4e+2,
  exponent-product={},
  retain-explicit-plus
}

\begin{document}

\num{6.76127E+17}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It works successfully. Best regards.

Comment: @panxia, if answer solve your problem (on the best way), you should accept them (by clicking on the check mark at the top left side of answer). As I see, so far you not accept any answer ...

Comment: @Zarko Oh, no, don't worry for me....:-)...For me it is not important...Always all the best.